# Want to show data horizontally in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have one table which contains following fields:
City nvarchar(50), 
TestName nvarchar(200), 
Method nvarchar(500), 
Cap nvarchar(3), 
Unit nvarchar(3)

I don't want to display data like

```
City || Testname  || Method || Cap || Unit
```

instead I want to display data in following manner:

```
TestName  || City ||    City1   ||   City2   ||          
          ||      ||CAP || Unit ||CAP || Unit||
```

Any idea to format data in this form ?

Using SQL or C#.net code?

Comment: if you want show it like this on the client, I'd strongly recomment to do this in C#. You can do this in SQL, but it's harder and SQL is not very well suited for this.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066927/what-are-some-good-ways-to-transpose-data-in-a-sql-table-from-row-columns-to-col

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you cannot produce such a setup.

What you can do is create a C# program and use some of the Grid libraries that exist. Just to name a few, you may check `Telerik` and `DevExpress`, which have powerful grid controls. They both come at a cost, and i have not used anyone else.

You would have to "split" the table into `master` - `detail` form and feed the grids.

**Disclaimer**

I am not trying to advertise the afore mentioned products. It is just a personal opinion. I have used both and i am fond of DevExpress, but must be many other powerful libraries.

Answer (score 0):

May be so:

```
select TestName, City, City City1, City City2, '', Cap CAP, Unit, Cap CAP, Unit Unit
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is

```
DECLARE  @sql  NVARCHAR(MAX),
         @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT ',
MAX(CASE WHEN [City] = ''' + [City] + ''' THEN [Cap] ELSE NULL END) AS [' + [City] + 'Cap],
MAX(CASE WHEN [City] = ''' + [City] + ''' THEN [Unit] ELSE NULL END) AS [' + [City] + 'Unit]'
FROM Table1
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY City 
FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')

SET @sql = 'SELECT [Testname], ' + @cols + '  FROM Table1 GROUP BY [Testname]'

PRINT @sql

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

It produces a table with the following structure

```
Testname | City1Cap | City1Unit | City2Cap | City2Unit | City3Cap | City3Unit | etc.
```